# Angular - How to redirect to Dashboard based on user role

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I have a project with ASP.NET Core as backend and Angular-13 as frontend.

I have this reponse on POSTMAN when user successfully logs in:

```
{
   "status_code": 200,
   "message": "Successfully Logged In",
   "result": {
       "token": "gggggffffffffffffdddddddddddd",
       "user": {
           "id": 3,
           "user_name": "smith",
           "last_login": "2022-01-03T12:35:26.0305649"
          },
       "roles": [
           "Teacher"
       ],
   }
}
```

This is the Angular code:

`user.ts`:

```
export interface IResponse<T> {
  message: string;
  error: boolean;
  code: number;
  results: T;
}

export interface IUser {
  userName?: string;
  lastLogin?: Date;
  token?: string;
  roles?: string[];
  expires?: Date;
}
```

`auth.service.ts`:

```
export class AuthService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  private currentUserSource = new ReplaySubject<IUser>(1);
  currentUser$ = this.currentUserSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  login(model: any){
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl+'auth/login', model).pipe(
      map((res: IUser)=>{
        const user = res;
        if(user){
          this.setCurrentUser(user);
        }
      })
    )
  }

  setCurrentUser(user: IUser){
    if(user){
      user.roles = [];
      const roles = this.getDecodedToken(user.token).role;//copy token to jwt.io see .role
      Array.isArray(roles) ? user.roles = roles : user.roles.push(roles);
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
      this.currentUserSource.next(user);
    }
  }

  getDecodedToken(token: string) {
    return JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]));
  }
}
```

On Angular frontend, I have two dashboards:   teacher-dashboard and student-dashboard

auth.component:

```
createForm() {
  this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
    UserName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    Password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(80)])
  })
}

login(){
  this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(res=>{
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
  }, error=>{
    this.toastr.error(error.error);
  })
}
```

If user successfully logs in. If the user's role is Teacher it should redirect to teacher-dashboard and if the role is student, it should redirect to student-dashboard.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you might want to use guards

> ng g guard isTeacher

> ng g guard isStudent

For each guard, inject a service then return true false based on logic.

If you use component on routing, use canActivate.

If you use loadChildren, use canLoad.

```html
{
    path: '/teacher',
    canLoad: [isTeacher],
    loadChildren: () => import('teacher.module').then(m => m.somethingmodule),
  }

{
    path: '/teacher',
    canActivate: [isTeacher],
    component: teacherComp,
  }
```

Same goes for students.

Why use guards? So if you are a student, you can not navigate by mistake or view teacher components. It still can be bypassed since it's all frontend but still.